# Facebook Messenger Bot fails to respond

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

We have just been approved for a bot and during a first beta test i noticed that the bot wasn't responding to some specific users.
The issue seems to be the user ids given by the messenger.
When trying to use the send api we get (**#100**) No matching user found . 
I found a thread in facebook but this seems to be about test users in particular.
( [Link for same](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/230322797329131))
Has anybody else experienced this behavior?
For the majority of the users everything works.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue - I've got NO idea what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this issue https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/578746852290927/

> We decided to switch our encoding to use strings instead of ints for user & page IDs and the change will be pushed next Tuesday. 
>   You can use json-bigint JSON parser as a workaround until then.

Comment: Currently on @TheStartupBus heading to Boulder. Fingers crossed for the fix getting deployed tomorrow. Pitching wouldn't be the same without it.

Comment: The fix is not added yet but you should check out that page for workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was

I am sending **recipient id instead sender id** in my json data.

> `dict_to_send = {
>      'message': {'text': u'hello FB'},
>      'recipient': {'id': 'sender_id_here'}
>   }
>   res = requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=your_token_here", 
> data=json.dumps(dict_to_send), headers = {'content-type':'application/json'})`